# cannot access columns in hive external table

Tags: hive, hdfs

After using the command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(
        item_id String,
        recommended_list String)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    ESCAPED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED By '\n'
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    location '/user/kite/items';
```

A table is created. And when I use

```
select * from items limit 2;
```

I get

```
100885        107525,562214
100023        655555,222222
```

as expected. However,

```
 select item_id from items;
gives me an error
   Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
java.io.IOException: cannot find dir = maprfs:///user/kite/items in pathToPartitionInfo: [maprfs:/user/kite/items]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getPartitionDescFromPathRecursively(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getPartitionDescFromPathRecursively(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat$CombineHiveInputSplit.<init>(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1098)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1090)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:931)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:882)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:882)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:856)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1088)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:901)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(cannot find dir = maprfs:///user/kite/items in pathToPartitionInfo: [maprfs:/user/kite/items])'
```

Comment: Your code refers to one location and your error message to another. Care to explain?

Comment: I edited it to avoid confusion. I did not want to share the exact location publicly.

Comment: So you want help with location related error but you are not willing to share the location. Seems counter productive.

Comment: Use `show create table` / `desc formatted` to verify the actual location

Comment: I verified it. I can do hadoop fs -text user/kite/items and see the items. Even select *  works only when I specify a column name it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the file name and extension under /user/kite/items?

I faced exact same issue, I tried the following: 
1. Delete the hive table
2. Rename the file (previously without an extension) to a csv file 
3. Recreate the table. Now I'm able to access individual columns and play around as usual.